# Trouble Getting Jquery Ui Datepicker working on site

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to get the jquery ui datepicker to work a page. I have it as:

```
<!--Datepicker CSS file link-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="jscripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $("#ud_Date_Taken").datepicker();
    });
});
</script>
```

With a link to:

```
Date Taken:<input type="text" id="ud_Date_Taken" name="ud_Date_Taken" value="<?php echo $date_brwd; ?>" class="input_style" /><br />
```

I have the javascripts in /basedir/jscripts. Looking at the debugger console in firefox it says **ReferenceError: $ is not defined on line 18** which is $(document).ready(function(){ line. I've looked at several examples on line on how to implement Datepicker and they match what I've written. If anybody has an idea on what might be the problem I would much appreciate.Thanks.

Comment: Ok I found one problem. on the src link I was using relative instead of absolute path. Adding a leading forward slash datepicker is now rendering. The trouble is the calendar has no styling what so ever.

Comment: There is a conflict between the two css link tags. If I comment out my main css link tag the datepicker calendar looks fine and I also change the css link to the Google http site. Anyone know how I might resolve this conflict.